# how to transfer value specific column datagridview in form 2 to datagridview in form 1 with key event enter twice in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, datatable, datagridview

so I want to transfer values ​​from specific column datagridview from form2 with key event enter twice to datagridview form1 can I implement it like please guide me.

Code in form 1

```
If Not Found Then
                            Form2.Show()
                            Dim f2 = Application.OpenForms.OfType(Of Form2).First()
                            Dim columntwo = f2.DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells(1).Value.ToString
                            Dim columnthree = f2.DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells(2).Value.ToString
                            FillDataTable(iRow, columntwo, _BBarcode, columnthree, newValue)
                                Grid.DataSource = _myTable
                                BtxtBarcode.Clear()
                            End If
```

Code in form 2

```
 Private Sub Form2_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Dim item = iService.Getitem2(Form1.Btxtcodeproduct.Text)
        DataGridView1.DataSource = item
        DataGridView1.Columns(0).Visible = False
  End Sub
 Private Sub DataGridView1_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.KeyDown
        If e.KeyData = Keys.Enter + Keys.Enter Then
            Dim col As Integer = DataGridView1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex
            Dim row As Integer = DataGridView1.CurrentCell.RowIndex
            DataGridView1.CurrentCell = DataGridView1(col, row)
            e.Handled = True
        End If
    End Sub
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Not wanting to get into another long stream of comments but think something like this is what you're wanting to do.
You still seem a little confused about Default form instances vs running instances so suggest you do some reading on that.

```
If Not Found Then
   Dim f2 as new Form2()
 
   Dim columntwo = f2.DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells(1).Value.ToString
   Dim columnthree = f2.DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells(2).Value.ToString
   FillDataTable(iRow, columntwo, _BBarcode, columnthree, newValue)
   Grid.DataSource = _myTable

   f2.ShowDialog()

   BtxtBarcode.Clear()

End If
```

Notice the ShowDialog() which will halt processing of this code until f2 is closed.  You can even start looking at the DialogResult to deal with users cancelling f2.  Heaps of info out there on how to work with that.
Where that line of code needs to be might need to be shuffled up and down a bit depending on what you need to happen before and after it is shown.

And as mentioned in your other question(s), you will need look at the Access Modifier property of the controls on Form2 so Form1 can access them

Comment: thank you for your answer, I tried to change according to your recommendations but there is an error `object refence not set to an instance of an object'

Comment: Sorry, but I'm going to have to wash my hands of you.  You seem to be against doing any work yourself, and when you ask questions you give incomplete questions missing critical detail.  If this code is giving you an null object reference error, there are 2 causes.  1) the code you provided in the question doesn't work anyway and generates the same error. 2) There is something else in your program unconnected to this causing the error.  Either way you've not given the info for anyone to help

Comment: All in all, for this site to be of any real use to you, you need to ask full and complete questions containing all relevant information.  Will also point out here, the participants on this site are here to help you for free, not to spoon feed you every possible solution when it seems you are unwilling to learn or do your own research to apply the principles you've been given.